# Computer making physical clicking noise when moving exposure sliders in Photoshop?

Tags: audio, graphics-card, adobe-photoshop, noise, clicking-sound

Specs:

- i7 5820k
- Corsair H110i GTX AIO Cooler
- 32GB DDR4
- Corsair CX750M PSU
- EVGA GTX 980
- MSI X99A SLI PLUS
- Main HDD is an SSD- my backup- and completely unrelated drive is mechanical.

The only moderately old piece of hardware in my system in the GPU and PSU- everything else is less than a year old.

--

See this video to see exactly what the issue is; quite hard to explain in words:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a7bx7NKjtuE

--

Essentially I guess, regardless of me disabling/unplugging all audio outputs, the computer, specifically in Photoshop, after adding multiple layers, makes a clicking noise when adjusting the exposure slider. Again, this is NOT related to my audio devices, as I have tested this with them all disabled/removed. This is my computer physically making these clicks.

As you can see in the video, the clicks are not random. They are directly related to the sliders. Please keep in mind that I had a seperate mic up for just the computer, it was inside of the PC recording and I just added the recording in the video, the clicks are not loud at all which is why I had to do that, and so you could hear/see exactly what I heard/see since my phone mic didn't pick it up.

What could this mean? Is it a standard issue? How exactly does this happen?

Thank you.

Comment: They're more like beeps than clicks. Where are they coming from?  Speakers?  Monitor?  Computer?  I've seen something similar before, and it's usually graphics related, almost sounds like interference?  Maybe try another video cable and/or port on both GPU and monitor?

Comment: My previous graphics card did something similar under load. I believe it's called 'coil whine'. It's caused by coils on the graphics card doing something, and for some reason physics makes it so that you can hear that. (I'm very obviously not a computer hardware specialist). In some cases it'll go away, but I RMA'd my card and the replacement didn't do it.

Comment: @DarkMoon got an entirely new GPU yesterday, GTX 1070, still doing the exact same thing. Quite odd

Comment: I was talking about the ports and cables. The card would have been my last resort, as it's the most expensive bit. :-P Do you have another cable, or even better, the ability to use a different  port type (DVI, HDMI, DisplayPort, even VGA for testing)?